# Android: Is it possible to get notified when enter/quit TouchMode?

Tags: android, view, touch

When system enters into TouchMode, I'd like to know which widget will lose focus. When system quits TouchMode, I'd also like to know which widget will get focus. Overriding onFocusChange() didn't satisfy me, since it couldn't tell TouchMode change, since it could happen in every mode, touch, trackball, key navigation, etc.

SDK said only one API View.isInTouchMode() there it is. So, is it possible to detect TouchMode change?

Answer (score 0):

Long shot but you probably need to maintain states manually. So you keep a a flag , lets say isTouchMode which you can set every time any of the widgets are touched and unset when something gets focus.

Comment: It should work, but it's also tedious. thx, any better solution?

Comment: It still doesn't work. Both trackball and touchscreen use MotionEvent, I can't tell if the widget is really touched.

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewTreeObserver.addOnTouchModeChangeListener(). It will tell you when the mode changes.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html